# Automapper Mapping Exception with Model and private Properties

Tags: properties, model, automapper, viewmodel, automapping

I am using AutoMapper to map two objects. ViewModel and Model, where ViewModel Implements InotifyPropertyChanged. How can i map Model to ViewModel. Below is my scenario,

1. Model

   ```
   public class Model
   {
       public string ResultType { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. ViewModel

   ```
   public class ViewModel : Screen
   {
       private string _resultType;

       public string ResultType
       {
           get { return _resultType; }
           set
           {
               _resultType = value;
               NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ResultType);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create Map implementation

   ```
   mapper.CreateMap<Model, ViewModel>();
   mapper.CreateMap<ViewModel, Model>();
   mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

   var test1 = new Model() {ResultType = "Test Result"};
   var s1 = mapper.Map<ViewModel>(test1);
   ```

I get AutoMapper Mapping Exception when i call mapper.Map.

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>   Mapping types:
>   Model-> ViewModel
>   Support.Model -> Support.ViewModel

Comment: Please show your mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned, you aren't actually showing any mapping code. Based on what you've provided, do something like this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<Model, ViewModel>();
});
```

Here's a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YnZ1nw